# Different \pagestyle - doesn't accept last one

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm stuck again. -.- I'm currently creating a template for my projects works, thesis, ... and I tried to structure it with `\include` what really worked fine till now:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\textsc}
\parindent0em
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = 1in, includehead, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}
{....}
\fancypagestyle{dhbw}
{....}
\fancypagestyle{restriction}
{....}
\fancypagestyle{project_work}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
    \include{title_page}
    \restoregeometry
    \include{restriction_note}
    \include{progress_report}
    \restoregeometry
    \tableofcontents
    \include{introduction}
\end{document}
```

As you can see this is my main document and everything works fine till the TOC section. Indifferent where I insert the `\pagestyle{project_work}` it keeps ignoring the command and just puts the page number in the middle of the footer. The other headers contains graphics, but they'll be displayed correctly.

I searched the web and the threads, but I couldn't find any useful answer. It keeps driving me crazy and I think I'm overlooking something, but I don't know what.

Comment: `\tableofcontents` issues `\thispagestyle{plain}`, so you have to say also `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` adding the settings you want.

Comment: @egreg +1 for the right answer. :) I knew I was missing something. So easy and yet I overlooked it. You wanna post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables`, `\part` and `\chapter` issue also a

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
```

command. So, if you want non standard headers and footers in the initial pages for those document parts, you need to setup

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}
  {<settings>}
```

where `<settings>` are what you want in the `fancyhdr` syntax.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this without altering the `plain` style? I don't mean to alter `\chapter` either, but why can a `\thispagestyle{...}` not be overwritten by another `\thispagestyle{...}`?

Comment: @mafp If the TOC has more than one page, typing `\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{plain}` will instruct LaTeX to use the `plain` page style in the *last* TOC page. If you want to selectively alter the page style on initial pages you need to patch the commands.